# Troubleshooting GUI After April 6 2018 Upgrade (Still Popping Blocks)

Tags: daemon, hard-fork

So it's been a while since I opened up the GUI, and forgot to prepare for the April 6 update. I opened up the GUI on Aug 8 2018. The daemon started up, and began to sync, for about 12 hours.

It stopped syncing, so I started searching for how to fix it.

I went though a few guides. I ended up deleting a file called .p2psomething.bin in the hidden .bitmonero folder at the advice of one of the threads here on StackExchange. It still didn't fix anything.

I did one other step from that same thread, where I changed the amount of blocks the daemon synced each time to 10 (I think...I lost the thread) instead of 20.

I also tried connecting to a remote node instead of a local node. Also no results.

When I click on bitmonero.log I can see a variety of errors like:

```
contrib/epee/include/net/http_client.h:456  Unexpected recv fail
```

2018-08-09 20:04:05.620   0x7fff9f716380    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Problem fetching info-- rpc_request: 
2018-08-09 20:04:50.466   0x7fff9f716380    INFO    global

Or

*:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2018-08-09 20:01:33.532   0x7fff9f716380    INFO    global

However, I also see that it's currently "popping blocks". The current status is:

2018-08-09 20:26:34.740   0x7fff9f716380    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:462  Popping blocks... 1620196

It reduces the number by 100 each time.

Should I let it go through the rest of the blocks to pop? Seems like that will take a while.

I'm not sure if I should continue to troubleshoot to just start over. Thanks for any help!

*Mac OSX Sierra 10.13.6
*monero-gui-mac-x64-v0.12.3.0

Comment: let her roll.  It will get there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have let the daemon sync for 12hours on 0.11, a lot of blocks needs to be popped on 0.12 so you could start syncing again.
According to your description, I'll recommend you let it pop what's needed to be popped, and let it sync after that.
Obviously it will take time, but still less than starting over.